# How can I authenticate to IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, datadog

## Context

I am trying to integrate IBM MQ with DataDog following [this](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/ibm_mq/?tab=host) documentation.
However, the DataDog agent fails to authenticate.
​

## What's not working

When running datadog-agent status I am getting:

```bash
$ datadog-agent status
...
ibm_mq (3.22.0)
    ---------------
      Instance ID: ibm_mq:5d5551cfb3b60a9a [WARNING]
      Configuration Source: file:/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/ibm_mq.d/conf.yaml
      Total Runs: 10
      Metric Samples: Last Run: 2, Total: 20
      Events: Last Run: 0, Total: 0
      Service Checks: Last Run: 5, Total: 50
      Average Execution Time : 16ms
      Last Execution Date : 2022-08-17 12:21:28 UTC (1660738888000)
      Last Successful Execution Date : 2022-08-17 12:21:28 UTC (1660738888000)
​
      Warning: Error getting queue stats for TEST_TOM: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2035: FAILED: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
      Warning: Error getting pcf queue status for TEST_TOM: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2035: FAILED: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
      Warning: Error getting pcf queue reset metrics for TEST_TOM: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2035: FAILED: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

## Configurations

To help you help me I will list some of my configurations below.

Note that for testing purpose (and as a desperate attempt), I added a "dd-agent" user in the mqm group which is group that runs the IBM MQ process (as recommended by the documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=systems-managing-mqm-group))​

##### user

```bash
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep "\(mqm\|dd-agent\)"
...
mqm:x:999:1001::/var/mqm:
dd-agent:x:113:118::/opt/datadog-agent:/usr/sbin/nologin
​
$ cat /etc/group | grep "\(mqm\|dd-agent\)"
...
mqm:x:1001:dd-agent
dd-agent:x:118:dd-agent
```

​

##### systemd

```bash
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/datadog-agent.service
...
[Unit]
Description=Datadog Agent
After=network.target
Wants=datadog-agent-trace.service datadog-agent-process.service datadog-agent-sysprobe.service datadog-agent-security.service
​
[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/opt/datadog-agent/run/agent.pid
User=dd-agent
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/opt/datadog-agent/bin/agent/agent run -p /opt/datadog-agent/run/agent.pid
# Since systemd 229, should be in [Unit] but in order to support systemd <229,
# it is also supported to have it here.
StartLimitInterval=10
StartLimitBurst=5
​
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

​​

##### ibm_mq.d/conf.yaml

```bash
$ cat conf.d/ibm_mq.d/conf.yaml
...
init_config:
​
instances:
  - queue_manager: QM.FOO.STAGING
    channel: QM.FOO.STAGING.APP
    host: 11.11.111.1
    port: 2514
    auto_discover_queues: false
    queues:
    - TEST_TOM
```

​

## How I verified if I have the right access

##### Applied permissions

```bash
$ su - mqm
$ dspmqaut -m QM.FOO.STAGING -t qmgr -p dd-agent
...
Entity dd-agent has the following authorizations for object QM.FOO.STAGING:
        inq
        set
        connect
        altusr
        crt
        dlt
        chg
        dsp
        setid
        setall
        ctrl
        system
​
$ dspmqaut -m QM.FOO.STAGING -t queue -n "TEST_TOM" -p dd-agent
...
Entity dd-agent has the following authorizations for object TEST_TOM:
        get
        browse
        put
        inq
        set
        crt
        dlt
        chg
        dsp
        passid
        passall
        setid
        setall
        clr
​​
​
$ dspmqaut -m QM.FOO.STAGING -t channel -n QM.FOO.STAGING.APP -p dd-agent
...
Entity dd-agent has the following authorizations for object QM.FOO.STAGING.APP:
        crt
        dlt
        chg
        dsp
        ctrl
        ctrlx
```

​

## Versions

IBM MQ version:

```bash
$ /opt/mqm/bin/dspmqver
...
Name:        IBM MQ
Version:     9.0.4.0
Level:       p904-L171031.DE
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    IBM MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 4.4.0-1113-aws
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 904
LicenseType: Developer
```

DataDog agent version:

```bash
$ datadog-agent status
...
=============
Process Agent
=============
​
  Version: 7.38.2
  Status date: 2022-08-17 12:13:42.363 UTC (1660738422363)
  Process Agent Start: 2022-08-17 10:23:50.682 UTC (1660731830682)
  Pid: 17213
  Go Version: go1.17.11
  Build arch: amd64
  Log Level: DEBUG
  Enabled Checks: [process rtprocess]
  Allocated Memory: 12,617,008 bytes
  Hostname: i-081a004251a122513
```

​
S.O version:

```bash
$ cat /etc/os-release
...
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

## Log

Posting results from the `AMQERR01.LOG` log file:

```
$ cat  /var/mqm/qmgrs/QM\!HTNG\!STAGING/errors/AMQERR01.LOG
...
----- amqzfubx.c : 1566 -------------------------------------------------------
08/18/2022 11:30:28 AM - Process(7334.41359) User(mqm) Program(amqzlaa0)
                    Host(ip-99-70-179-7) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.0.4.0) QMgr(QM.HTNG.STAGING)
                    Time(2022-08-18T11:30:28.289Z)
                    RemoteHost(10.20.178.7)
                    ArithInsert1(0) ArithInsert2(0)
                    CommentInsert1(ubuntu)
                    CommentInsert2(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE)
                    CommentInsert3(get)

AMQ8077W: Entity 'ubuntu' has insufficient authority to access object
'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.

EXPLANATION:
The specified entity is not authorized to access the required object. The following requested permissions are unauthorized: get
ACTION:
Ensure that the correct level of authority has been set for this entity against
the required object, or ensure that the entity is a member of a privileged
group.
```

Interestingly... I tried to look for the user `dd-agent` in the log and I realized that it doesn't exist in the log (it seems to be using the Ubuntu user).

I got `emtpy` when I tried to look for the user as you can see here:

```bash
$ cat /var/mqm/qmgrs/QM\!HTNG\!STAGING/errors/AMQERR01.LOG | grep dd-agent
...
empty
```

Happy to provide further information if needed

### Update

I followed the tip from [JoshMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7264620/joshmc) to look at the `AMQERR01.LOG` log file and it seems like the DataDog agent is not using the `dd-agent` user despite defining in the configurations. I am not sure why is this the case

Comment: Please look into the queries manager's AMQERR01.LOG to see a more specific cause of the 2035 error.  Please edit and add it to the question.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc! I added the log as requested. Interestingly I realized that it seems not to be using the dd-agent user and using the ubuntu one instead. I am now trying to see how I can enable it to use the right user (no luck so far). This might be the cause potentially

Comment: Are you authenticating with a user/password?

Comment: Hi @JoshMc! With your tip about looking at the `AMQERR01.LOG` I was able to find what I was doing wrong. If you post this as an answer I would be happy to mark it as accepted

Comment: Did you need to add ADOPTCTX(YES) to your AUTHINFO object?